# Relation between isentropic/isenthalpic to adiabatic?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

We have $dQ = T dS$. Does this imply that a process is adiabatic $dQ = 0$ if and only if it is isentropic $dS = 0$ for any process? 
This does not sound right, as this would mean that there is no point in distinguishing these two cases.

Also we have the enthalpy defined by $H = E + pV$. This gives us $dH = dE + d(pV)$. If we assume that $p$ is constant, then by the first law of thermodynamics $dH = dE + p dV = dQ$. So for any reversible process isenthalpic should be the same as adiabatic. Does this make sense?

Comment: consider irreversible adiabatic processes

Comment: well, my question is rather: Where is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: $dQ = TdS$ is ok when you have a well defined path on the diagram. If you system undergoes a path which is not well specified on the diagram this equation makes no sense

Comment: which property of a system determines if there exists such a well-defined path?

Comment: reversibility implies this. also if your system undergoes a transformation through a large sequence of small changes, this also defines a path, which gets better with the number of intermediate steps

Comment: So a reversible process is adiabatic iff it is isentropic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have dQ=TdS. Does this imply that a process is adiabatic dQ=0 if and only if it is isentropic dS=0 for any process?

Remember the interpretation of each quantity: S is a function of state,  Q is not, it is heat flow. So even if they are related they are completely different concepts. But it is correct to say that if a **reversible** process (so S is defined all the time) is adiabatic, then it is isentropic.

> So for any reversible process isenthalpic should be the same as adiabatic

The increase in enthalpy of a system is equal to the added heat, provided that the system is under constant pressure and that the only work done by the system is expansion work. So for any reversible process isenthalpic should be the same as adiabatic only if p is constant (that is, if it also isobaric).